# What is the Android best practice if Activity or Fragment does not contain required intent or argument?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

If my Activity/Fragment requires that the coder provide a particular intent or argument, how should I handle the case where the coder did not provide this intent or argument?

Say I have the following Activity and Fragment:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String KEY = "KEY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (!getIntent().hasExtra(KEY)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("KEY is required");
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String KEY = "KEY";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (!getArguments().containsKey(KEY)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("KEY is required");
        }

        //...
    }

}
```

My gut tells me just to throw an Exception and force the app to shut down so the coder can rectify this problem in their code. If so then which Exception best describe this situation?

Furthermore, where is the best place to place such a code? For example, onCreat() for Activity? Or onAttach() or onCreateView() for Fragment?

Comment: Sorry I meant coder. If my activity/fragment is a reuseable piece of code, this will ensure the coder knows what my activity or fragment needs.

Comment: And if the coder isn't me? The other coder would not know what it needs. Please refer to this example from Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents where a ClassCastException is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always throw Exception, just make sure the describe the error in details to help other devs understand what they did wrong.

Also, Remember that it's always better to "fail early" than to postpone the Exception -

If there is a critical data you need, validate the data **as soon as you can** and don't "hide" the Exception under some button click of specific user flow - you want it to be clear as soon as someone opens the Activity to minimize the risk the dev won't notice his/hers error.

**P.S**

There is a nice pattern to minimize that kind of coding errors.
You can create a public static method to instantiate your Fragments and Activities.

Example:

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context context, String requiredStr, int requiredInt) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("extra_str", requiredStr);
        intent.putExtra("extra_int", requiredInt);
        return intent;
    }
```

That way the dev doesn't have to remember all the required data. 
And then you can start your Activity like so:

```
startActivity(MyActivity.newIntent(context, "string", 20));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is totally reasonable to crash the app when it enters an invalid state due to programmer error. Fail fast and fail early. Of course you should include an error message that explains how the programmer can correct the error.

If a required value isn't present in an `Intent` or a `Bundle`, I would say the most natural exception to throw would be `NullPointerException`. You could also throw `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @Vanna That exception is part of the Java Simple Argument Parser framework.  I don't see any indication that the developer is using JSAP so it probably isn't applicable.

Comment: @Vanna Sure, but I wouldn't make a developer deal with your custom exception when there's `IllegalStateException` that is perfectly suitable as long as a descriptive error message is supplied.  I would only make a custom exception type if there is nothing in the JDK that fits.

Comment: @Vanna the next sentence says `application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation` which fits perfectly... the developer did not populate the `Bundle` or `Intent` with the proper information, so the system is in a bad state.

Comment: "Either OP is working with a team of alzheimer patients or he doesn't trust the coders/himself."  I got the impression he's writing this as a library to be used by some unknown developer, in which case he is absolutely right not to trust them.  If this is for use within his organization, then I like your custom exception option a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

This exception will occur only while developing application. If users get this exception then development is useless.

And while developing, to show developers some error in a organized way is nothing but to make it meaningful and understanding easily.

Though , here a simple toast or error log or alertdialog could be enough because end level users would never see this type of data passing exceptions!

To make app crash you can use [UnsupportedOperationException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) because, here activity is changing (operation) without data (not supported).

Also you can use [NullPointerException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) because some variable(which would be used in next step) is not getting value (null).

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` is for the case when a method is called that isn't implemented or supported.  In this case the method is supported, but the inputs are missing.  `IllegalStateException` or `IllegalArgumentException` would be better.